# Virtual host not working in xmapp (Using different port for localhost :7777)

Tags: zend-framework2, virtualhost

I'm using local host port 7777. When I try to virtually host a zend framework application. It doesn't work for me. Any explantion why is that
Note : I'm using xampp in windows 10 platform. As below files in the system i have change it. Let know what i have done worng?

**F:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf**

```
Listen 7777
```

**F:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

NameVirtualHost *:80

VirtualHost *:80

```
 ServerName album
 DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/album/public"
 SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
 Directory "F:/xampp/htdocs/album/public"
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
 Directory
```

VirtualHost

**c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\host**

127.0.0.1          album

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to set the 7777 port here:

```
NameVirtualHost *:7777

VirtualHost *:7777
```